# Using csv-parse with highlandjs

Tags: node.js, csv, node-streams

I would like to do a bit of parsing on csv files to convert them to JSON and extract data out of them. I'm using highland as a stream processing library. I am creating an array of csv parsing streams using

```
import { readdir as readdirCb, createReadStream } from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import _ from 'highland';
import parse from 'csv-parse';

const readdir = promisify(readdirCb);

const LOGS_DIR = './logs';
const options = '-maxdepth 1'; 

async function main() {
  const files = await readdir(LOGS_DIR)
   const stream = _(files)
        .map(filename => createReadStream(`${LOGS_DIR}/${filename}`))
            .map(parse)

}

main();
```

I have tried to use `stream` like:

```
 const stream = _(files)
        .map(filename => createReadStream(`${LOGS_DIR}/${filename}`))
        .map(parse)
        .each(stream => {
             stream.on('parseable', () => {
                 let record
                 while (record = stream.read()) { console.log(record) }
             })
        })
```

This does not produce any records. I am not sure as how to proceed and receive the JSON for each row for each CSV file.

EDIT:

Writing a function like this works for an individual file:

```
import parse from 'csv-parse';
import transform from 'stream-transform';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';


export default function retrieveApplicationIds(filename) {
  console.log('Parsing file', filename);
  return createReadStream(filename).pipe(parser).pipe(getApplicationId).pipe(recordUniqueId);
}
```

Edit 2:

I have tried using the concat streams approach:

```
const LOGS_DIR = './logs';

function concatStreams(streamArray, streamCounter = streamArray.length) { 
  streamArray.reduce((mergedStream, stream) => {
    // pipe each stream of the array into the merged stream
   // prevent the automated 'end' event from firing
    mergedStream = stream.pipe(mergedStream, { end: false });
    // rewrite the 'end' event handler
    // Every time one of the stream ends, the counter is decremented.
    // Once the counter reaches 0, the mergedstream can emit its 'end' event.
    stream.once('end', () => --streamCounter === 0 && mergedStream.emit('end'));
    return mergedStream;
  }, new PassThrough());
}

async function main() {
  const files = await readdir(LOGS_DIR)
  const streams = files.map(parseFile);
  const combinedStream = concatStreams(streams);
  combinedStream.pipe(process.stdout); 
}

main();
```

When I use this, I get the error:

> (node:1050) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added to [Transformer]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit